# Warning: Failed to decode resource from state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud

I am really needing your brains. I believe AWS upgraded its version recently. For the last 2-3 days I’ve been having all kinda errors when I do ‘tf plan’ or ‘tf apply’. I did upgrade my TF Cloud version and AWS version as well. This is the error I’m getting mostly.

```txt
Warning: Failed to decode resource from state
│ 
│ Error decoding "module.nfg-prod.aws_iam_role.nfg_ec2_role" from prior
│ state: unsupported attribute "role_last_used"
╵
╷
│ Warning: Failed to decode resource from state
│ 
│ Error decoding "module.nfg-prod.aws_autoscaling_group.app_asg" from prior
│ state: unsupported attribute "tags"
╵
╷
│ Warning: Failed to decode resource from state
│ 
│ Error decoding "module.nfg-prod.aws_secretsmanager_secret.app_creds" from
│ prior state: unsupported attribute "rotation_enabled"
╵
╷
│ Warning: Failed to decode resource from state
│ 
│ Error decoding "module.nfg-prod.aws_iam_role.nfg_ecs_role" from prior
│ state: unsupported attribute "role_last_used"
╵
Failed generating plan JSON
Exit code: 1

Failed to marshal plan to json: error marshaling prior state: unsupported attribute "role_last_used"
Operation failed: failed generating plan JSON: failed running command (exit 1)
```

My TF version:

```txt
Terraform v1.7.0
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.33.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.6.0
```

Tried to change the versions for TF Cloud

Tried to change the versions for TF Cloud, 'tf state pull'. download 'tf state' from previous week, when it wasn't giving me any problems, tried to delete .terraform and etc. 'tf init' works perfectly fine.

Comment: What is the terraform version in the state file?

Comment: hello Marko E, thank you for response. This is my tfstate:

{
    "version": 3,
    "serial": 3,
    "lineage": "d6d70d7b-3f48-0de0-14a3-183e59fdfae5",
    "backend": {
        "type": "cloud",
        "config": {
            "hostname": null,
            "organization": "PG",
            "token": null,
            "workspaces": {
                "name": "production"

Can you tell what could I do?

Comment: Very strange ... I'm not seeing anything in the Doc for aws_iam_role about the `role_last_used`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role can you share the code to create that resource

Comment: If this is urgent for you, the fastest way is to manually delete those resources from state and AWS then let Terraform recreate them, if deleting will cause unacceptable downtime an alternative will be to import them

Comment: I just tested with older versions (Terraform v1.6.2)  and (provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.49.0) there was no `role_last_used` in the state ... in your case I would just try manually removing those that error with `unsupported attribute` and try the plan again

Comment: Hello Helder Sepulveda, I tried to remove one of the warnings from the state, but gave me an error:

tf state rm "module.nfg-prod.module.alb.aws_lb.this[0]"                 
Removed module.nfg-prod.module.alb.aws_lb.this[0]
Error saving the state: unsupported attribute "role_last_used"

The state was not saved. No items were removed from the persisted
state. No backup was created since no modification occurred. Please
resolve the issue above and try again.

Comment: @MahmudRahimberganov The state file does not show terraform version used?

Comment: Marko E, what do I need to do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, just needed to run the "terraform refresh" command!
Thanks everyone!